# Query failed with mysqli query

Tags: php

The code showing the query failed but can't get the point why is it happening. It is just for testing the code.

```
<?php
require_once("database_function.php");

class Auth {
    public $password = "123456a";
    public $username = "allen";
    public function matching() {
        Global $Database;

        $sql = "SELECT * FROM auth";
        $sql .= " WHERE username =" . $this->{'username'};
        $sql .= " AND password =" . $this->{'password'};
        $sql .= " LIMIT 1";
        $result = mysqli_query($Database-> connect, $sql);
        if ($result) {
            echo "Querying Successfull";
        } elseif (!$result) {
            echo "Querying failed";
        }
    }
}

$authentication = new Auth();
$authentication -> matching();

?>
```

Comment: Damn, I only just realized I'm at Programmers and not StackOverflow. This is not the right community for a question like yours!

Comment: Please, PLEASE use parameterized queries with mysqli_prepare (http://php.net/manual/en/mysqli.prepare.php) because this is the worst way to do queries. Go look up SQL Injection and the likes. It will also solve the problem you are having here I think. Also, don't do globals.

Comment: Please say that you are not storing the passwords in plain text.

Comment: Without an [mcve], this is off-topic.

Answer (score 1):

Use `$username` and `$password` Instead of `$this{'username'}` and `$this{'password'}`

```
<?php
    require_once ("database_function.php");

    class Auth {
        public $password = "123456a";
        public $username = "allen";
        public function matching () {
            Global $Database;
            $sql = "SELECT * FROM auth";
            $sql .= " WHERE username =".$username;
            $sql .= " AND password =".$password;
            $sql .= " LIMIT 1";
            $result = mysqli_query ($Database->connect, $sql);
            if ($result) {
                echo "Querying Successfull";
            } elseif (!$result) {
                echo "Querying failed";
            }
        }
    }

    $authentication = new Auth();
    $authentication -> matching();

?>
```

Comment: I appreciate this is the code from the OP, but it probably contains a SQL injection vulnerability, and that should not go unremarked. It also implies that passwords should be stored in plaintext, which is a separate security problem.

Answer (score 0):

This:
`$result = mysqli_query($Database-> connect, $sql);`

Should look like this:
`$result = mysqli_query($Database->connect, $sql);`

No space between the "`->`" and "connect".

And I second the params on the query. Little Bobby Tables.

Answer (score 0):

use single quote in field value
$sql .= " WHERE username ='" . $this->{'username'} ."'";
$sql .= " AND password ='" . $this->{'password'} ."'";